# Get field value before delete it

Tags: mysql, fetch, sql-delete

I have two table categories ( hierarchical structure ) and attachment that have relations together.

```
delete  from category where lft between @left and @right;
```

and I want to delete from attachment which is related by those category !

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
delete c,a category c 
 join attachment a on c.id=a.category_id 
 where c.lft between @left and @right
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using FOREIGH KEYS with InnoDB [MySQl and Foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) and define ON DELETE - CASCADE option for the key that relates categories and attachment tables.

Second one is just `DELETE FROM attachments WHERE category_id BETWEEEN @left AND @right;`